# the meaning of "I was assigned"

Tags: meaning-in-context

*I love style manuals. Ever since **I was assigned** Strunk and White’s The Elements of Style in an introductory psychology course, the writing guide has been among my favorite literary genres.* [Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=Qd2YoAEACAAJ&dq=isbn:9780670025855)

I am thinking over the exact meaning of "I was assigned" in my sentence. Although I checked out the dictionaries, none of the possible meanings does not make much sense. The one and only alternative that I find as being suitable is the meaning "to give out as a task". So the author says that at the university – maybe within a seminar – he had to deal with the textbook on style. Am I right?

Comment: That sounds exactly right. To be “*assigned* a book” is to be given the task of reading it in a course.

Comment: +1 to Lynn. We were given our reading assignment for the week: the teacher assigned us the first three chapters of the biology textbook.  Passive: we were assigned the first three chapters...

Comment: The verb _assigned_ here means _assigned to read_. It's a common usage in academia. Evidently, _Strunk and White_ was a required book for the course.

Answer (score 1):

"The Elements of Style" is a book by Strunk & White.

The verb assign is used in many senses.  Speaking in the context, it has two senses as follows:

1. To give or allot someone something to use.
2. To give someone a job or task as part of their duty or course of study.

As the book was given to you to study in your introductory course, it's most probably a task given as part of your studies. So the sentence means as follows:

Ever since I was given the task of reading/studying Strunk & White's book "The Elements of Style" in an introductory psychological course, ......

Comment: Does a teacher provide a student with homework to use? I don't think your post answers the question. To *provide* has multiple meanings and I don't think it works for to *assgn*.

Comment: Rathony, There's no mention of homework. Nor did i say that a teacher provided a student with homework to use. Your teacher may give you a book to read and learn from it.  I don't think he gave a job, duty, task. or homework to do. He  gave him the book so that he can simply read and learn from it.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what to *assign* means. There is no connotation that the book is given by anybody. It is what you have to read and understand in order to pass the course. That is an assignment.

Comment: Merriam Webster states assign also means to provide someone with something. Th eacher assigned us different books to read. I think there's nothing wrong with this sentences.

Comment: You used the verb *to use*, not *read*.

Comment: In the case of a textbook, to _use_ is to _read_.

Answer (score 0):

The verb to [*assign*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assign) is usually used by your boss (senior) at work or your teacher (professor) at school (university). It means

> to give someone a particular **job** or **duty** : to require someone to do a
>   particular task

When something is assigned to you, you usually have to read and write (often times analyze) something to satisfy expectation of those who assigned something. If you fails to do that, you will get various measures such as a failing grade, lower grade and demotion, etc. as a consequence.

You can rephrase the sentence to:

> Ever since Professor A gave me an assignment (homework) to read Strunk and
>   White’s The Elements of Style in an introductory psychology course...

[Merriam-Webster, Wiktionary]

Comment: Maybe, assigned means given in your sentence, if you are looking for the meaning of your sentence.  The word "assign"is usually used in passive form.

Comment: @Idon'tknowwhoIam. Where did I say the verb to *assign* is usually used in what form? Can you explain the difference in this [Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+assigned%2CHe+was+assigned%2C&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CHe%20assigned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CHe%20was%20assigned%3B%2Cc0)?

Comment: Learners reading this answer should know that _assignor_ is a rare word in day-to-day contexts. It would be more natural to say, "...to meet the expectations of the person who assigned you the work" (or, to just use that person's job title, e.g., "...of your teacher" or "of your boss").